# Help with Batch Files?

Tags: file, batch-file

What are batch files useful for? They just seem to be used to make viruses and other things...but it seems like shell scripting to me.

Whats the uses for batch files?

Comment: yes, batch files are useful for making viruses and other things and they are like shell scripting.

Comment: They are shell scripts for the `cmd` interpreter. You can make viruses with Bash scripting, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) article at Wikipedia:

> Batch files are useful for running a
>   sequence of executables  automatically
>   and are often used by system
>   administrators to automate tedious
>   processes. Unix-like  operating
>   systems (such as Linux) have a similar
>   type of file called a shell script.

A simple example:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *svn') do (  rd /s /q "%%i")
```

If you save the above line in a file called ClearSVNFolders.bat and after that execute a double click you'll delete every folder named svn that resides inside a root path...

You automated the whole process. You could easily spend hours doing the above task if you had a deep root directory, that is, one containing thousands of folders. :)

Comment: Provided you don't have any folders with Unicode names or have a TrueType font set for the console window.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are the Windows equivalent of a Unix shell script. So you can use them to automate things.

Answer (score 0):

You could use them for shell scripting. :-P

Of course, they kind of suck at that, compared to bash (or perl/python/tcl). But if you're on Windows, it's a one-horse race unless you want to install cygwin or msys and battle with Unix/Windows incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Batch Files are extremely useful. They are super easy to learn as well. you can make them do things on startup like say that a program wants to open itself and wont close even from taskman.exe you can force it to shutoff without warning.

or you could make games and ineractive things like i like to do.

i have a Messenger that i made with fully customizable colors and accounts with account management and servers.

But you probably dont trust me enough for you to download it.

But yea they are pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Batch file is "a computer file containing a list of instructions to be carried out in turn." 
We have been studying since childhood that computer is a dummy machine and this is a method of instructing a dummy machine.

For example :-

If you want to instruct the system to create a  folder with random name then type ,

```
@echo off
md %random%
```

Creating Batch files enables you to execute several line of CMD commands in a single file.

For example :-

```
@echo off
md %random%
tasklist
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire purpose of a  Batch script is to execute several DOS commands in sequence:

```
echo Hello!
set var=7
echo I just made var=%var%!
pause
```

It was invented in MS-DOS for user simplicity to execute things they did all the time, the most notable thing being "AUTOEXEC.BAT" which started once the command interpreter started, people would add things like:

```
echo Welcome to my computer!
```

or

```
cd C:\Games\
```

To make it quicker to access their games or whatever they needed.